# Managing core data threads in iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, core-data, ios7

Using Core data in objective c on main thread causes dead locks . For managing this i am using to Managed Object Context , one using NSMainQueueConcurrencyType and another using NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType. Here is code-

```
 - (NSManagedObjectContext *)mainQueueContext
 {
  if (!_mainQueueContext) {
    _mainQueueContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc]   initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
    _mainQueueContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator;
   }

   return _mainQueueContext;
 }

- (NSManagedObjectContext *)privateQueueContext
{
  if (!_privateQueueContext) {
    _privateQueueContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
    _privateQueueContext.persistentStoreCoordinator =     self.persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

 return _privateQueueContext;
}
```

I also have set Notifications-

```
- (void)contextDidSavePrivateQueueContext:(NSNotification *)notification
{
  @synchronized(self) {
    [self.mainQueueContext performBlock:^{
        [self.mainQueueContext  mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];
    }];
  }
}

- (void)contextDidSaveMainQueueContext:(NSNotification *)notification    
{
 @synchronized(self) {
    [self.privateQueueContext performBlock:^{
        [self.privateQueueContext     mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];
    }];
  }
}


- (id)init
 {
  self = [super init];
  if (self) {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self   selector:@selector(contextDidSavePrivateQueueContext:)name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification object:[self privateQueueContext]];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(contextDidSaveMainQueueContext:) name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification object:[self mainQueueContext]];
   }
   return self;
 }

 - (void)dealloc
 {
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
 }
```

Now my problem is in fetching records from Core data on background queue. My Code for fetching record is-

```
 -(NSArray *)fetchNameForStr:(NSString *)str
 {
  NSManagedObjectContext *childContext=[CoreDataStore privateQueueContext];
  __block NSArray *array=nil;
  [childContext performBlock:^{
  NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
  [request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Entity" inManagedObjectContext:childContext]];
  NSPredicate *predicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(name=%@)", str];
  [request setPredicate:predicate];
  [request setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
  NSError *error = nil;
  array = [childContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
  return array;

  }];
return dict;
}
```

The above function returns nil because fetching is performed asynchronously. How to put completion handler in it? How can I get the result which I can return from this function?
I am saving records in core data in the same way. Does that also cause problem in synchronising saving and fetching?

I stuck in this core data thread problem. Help me to get out of this.

Comment: In your function you are returning some arbitrary object `dict`. That is nil and has nothing to do with your fetch.

Comment: Ya i know it . I want to know how to control it ?

Comment: Return the results instead, not a nil object. Duh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use asynchronous requests the simplest way to get result - **to use blocks as arguments and change returning type to void**. And at the end of the block - call the argument block with result. Something like this:

```
typedef void (^ResultBlockType)(NSArray *resultArray, NSError *error);

- (void)fetchNameForStr:(NSString *)str resultBlock:(ResultBlockType)resultBlock {
        NSManagedObjectContext *childContext = [CoreDataStore privateQueueContext];
        __block NSArray *array = nil;
        [childContext performBlock:^{
         NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        [request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Entity" inManagedObjectContext:childContext]];
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(name=%@)", str];
        [request setPredicate:predicate];
        [request setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
        NSError *error = nil;
        array = [childContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
        resultBlock(array, error)

    }];
}
```